# Mysql having trouble with difficult order by

Tags: mysql

I am having issues with a query/view I am constructing.

The table structure:

- templateId (Int, Primary)
- attributeName (Varchar, Primary)
- x1 (Int)
- x2 (Int)
- Alignment (Enum[Left, Right])
- Position (Enum[Top, Bottom])
- Offset (Int)

I want to create a view that shows the results in the following order:

- First ordering, by templateId ASC.
- Second ordering, if Position=Top, then by Offset ASC, else if Position=Bottom, then by Offset DESC.

How do I go about creating it, especially with the second ordering in mind.

Regards.

Comment: Since templateID is the primary key, it will be unique. So the second ordering will never be used.

Comment: @Barmar The primary key is composite (templateId, attributeName)

Comment: @Barmar The combination of (templateId, attributeName) is the primary key.

Comment: What is the ordering between a Top element and a Bottom element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY templateId ASC,
    CASE Position WHEN 'Top' THEN 1 WHEN 'Bottom' THEN 2 END ASC,
    CASE Position WHEN 'Top' THEN Offset ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE Position WHEN 'Bottom' THEN Offset ELSE NULL END DESC
```

Note you should also be able to use the following since 'Top' has a smaller index than 'Bottom':

```
ORDER BY templateId ASC,
    Position ASC,
    CASE Position WHEN 'Top' THEN Offset ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE Position WHEN 'Bottom' THEN Offset ELSE NULL END DESC
```

Comment: How this will behave if `Position` is neither `Top` nor `Bottom`?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux That cannot be the case as it is an Enum.

Comment: Somehow it puts the 'Bottom' results before the 'Top' results.

Comment: @skiwi Which do you want first? You didn't specify that.

Comment: @lc. Ah you are correct, I forgot to mention that. The 'Top' needs to come first.

Comment: Ok I added an explicit ordering. Also I'm not handling the NULL case for either position or offset. Are these nullable?

Comment: Thank you. Also actually you can replace your (extensive) second ordering clause by `Position ASC`, given that the enum order is `'Top', 'Bottom'`. Also they are not nullable.

Comment: @skiwi Yeah exactly, beat you to the punch by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY templateid ASC, IF(Position = 'top', offset, -offset) ASC
```

Comment: Afraid that this one won't work. As the ordering is also switched around (from ASC to DESC), when you switch from Top to Bottom.

Comment: Maybe not a problem in that particular case, but more generally I think this does not behave as expected if `offset` contains `NULL`values.

Comment: There is the minus which will make it work. Why dont you simply test it. Agree for Null values but it is not mentioned in the initial description

Comment: @NedretRecep I did test. Turns out that I want the ones with Position='Top' first, but forgot to put it on my OP.

Comment: So is there a third ordering criterion? I dont understand

Comment: `ORDER BY templateid ASC, (Position = 'top') DESC, IF(Position = 'top', offset, -offset) ASC`

Comment: It works aswell, but the other answer uses less 'black magic' in my opinion, as it shows the explicit control structure. In this answer the control structure is partly hidden in whether there is a minus before offset or not.